# Using aliases in stored procedures with JPA entity

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jdbc

I have a Workers table with column name: "WorkerID"
so I have created entity with @Column(name = "WorkerID").

Whenever I try to use stored procedure that selects WorkerID as ID, it doesn't work. It says The column name WorkerID is not valid.

Is there any annotation I can use to make the both parameters WorkerID and ID not to be mandatory? (so I can use this stored procedure and a simple select on workers table)

The exception given upon executing the query:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name worker_id is not valid.

Failed query:

> SELECT    Worker_ID AS [ID] From Workers

Working query:

> SELECT    Worker_ID From Workers

The entity:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Workers")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class Worker {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "Worker_ID")
protected long Worker_ID;

@Column(name = "Email")
private String Email;

@Column(name = "Username")
private String Username;

}
```

I want to be able to run both queries with the same entity. Is it feasible?

Thanks!

Comment: What is "It" ? Posting the exception + stack trace would say a whole lot more, as would posting the entity and the stored procedure

Comment: Added. Thanks @BillyFrost

Comment: so it is thrown by SQLServer in response to your query (i.e nothing to do with JPA as such), so you need to fix your query. Perhaps the column name has different case to what you claim to be using